# JavaScript How to create a new object in a function?

Tags: javascript, object, storage

I'm writing up a discord bot that will store a request from a message via an object.

The idea is you call a function that will create a new object that can be referenced as a way to store information, rather than having 1 giant file or variable that has to be referenced every time a request to display said information.

Currently my code is setup with a rudimentary version of what I want.

```
var order1 = {
    content: "",
    author: "",
}
var order2 = {
    content: "",
    author: "",
}
var order3 = {
    content: "",
    author: "",
}
```

Even from my limited experience of programming, I know that is something is repeated, and often, there is usually a more effective way to write it.

```
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    // Interpret Command
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    var messagecont = message.content.replace('!haul.order', "");   // Remove command string
 
    if(command === 'haul.order'){
        message.channel.send("Hual order for:" + messagecont  + " by: " + message.author.username);
        orderNum++; // Update the current number order
        if (orderNum > 3) {
            message.channel.send("Sorry we only have 3 storage objects! Our programmer is to lazy to fix 
            this!");
        }

        if (orderNum == 1) {
            order1.content = messagecont;
            order1.author = message.author.username + ". ";
        } else if (orderNum == 2) {
            order2.content = messagecont;
            order2.author = message.author.username + ". ";
        } else if (orderNum == 3) {
            order3.content = messagecont;
            order3.author = message.author.username + ". ";
        }

    } else if (command =="show.orders") {
        message.channel.send("Orderlist:" + order1.content + " by: " + order1.author + order2.content + " by: " + order2.author + order3.content + " by: " + order3.author);
    }
});
```

For demonstration this code currently has only three storage objects, however adding more would "fix" the issue but in the wrong way. I ask again, is there a way to create a new object via a function? Something like order1, than order2 gets created. I know Create.object() exists, but from my knowledge, it only applies a template to a variable you had to declare.

Comment: You could push orders to an array. Like `arr.push({content: 'xxx', author: 'yyy'});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more dynamic by storing the *orders* in an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). To such array you may [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) as many entries as you like.

```js
//REM: Containing all the orders
const _listOfOrders = [];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  //REM: Getting input values
  let tContent = document.getElementById('content')?.value || '';
  let tAuthor = document.getElementById('author')?.value || '';
  
  //REM: Adding the values to the list of orders
  _listOfOrders.push({
    Content: tContent,
    Author: tAuthor
  });
  
  //REM: Outputting the current list
  console.table(_listOfOrders)
});
```

```html
<input type = 'text' id = 'content' value = 'Content'>
<input type = 'text' id = 'author' value = 'Author'>
<button>order</button>
```

Open the console to see the result.

Comment: Additionally is there an easy way to edit the values in the array? Say if someone wants to update the content value? I know the index value is updated. The reason why I had objects used is so that they can be easily read and changed.

Comment: The only difference to before is, that instead of `order1` you have `_listOfOrders[0]`, instead of `order2` you have `_listOfOrders[1]`  and so on. So you can do the same things as before, just without having to preset a static set of object variables.

Comment: Also compared to before you can now use array functions, like `forEach` and `find` to your advantage.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how to thank you enough haha.